# Bazel build error when using the AWS SDK into my project

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, bazel, aws-sdk-go

I am trying to use the AWS SDK into my project, so I did an import of these modules:

```
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/iam"
```

all fine and well, I can get the list of IAM users on my local, but when I deploy and run Bazel, I find the following error:

```
bazelisk build //...
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_lee/e8d7ac4c02a67f34deebe5eff64aac05/external/com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2_service_sts/BUILD.bazel:3:11: in go_library rule @com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2_service_sts//:sts: target '@com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2_service_internal_presigned_url//:presigned-url' is not visible from target '@com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2_service_sts//:sts'. Check the visibility declaration of the former target if you think the dependency is legitimate
ERROR: Analysis of target '//service/octopus-api/infra/integration/aws:go_default_library' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '@com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2_service_sts//:sts' failed
```

It might be similar to another thread in Stack Overflow [Depending on an external library which depends on an internal package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67513946/depending-on-an-external-library-which-depends-on-an-internal-package)

Is there a way to solve this issue? I'm not familiar with Bazel so I don't know what other information could I provide to help find a solution. I have a BUILD.bazel file in the root folder of the project, let me know if I should share it, or if this is an issue that is related to the AWS SDK.

Going by the error log, it seems `com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2_service_internal_presigned_url` is not visible to `com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2_service_sts`. Any way to make it visible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please share the `BUILD` file and your full `bazel build` command?

Comment: @ShmulikKlein Yes, here is the BUILD file: https://pastebin.com/mjCyMqBq and judging by the Makefile, the build command is `bazelisk build //...`

Comment: That is the BUILD file in the root folder, but there is also a BUILD file in the folder of the package that uses the AWS SDK, and it looks like this: https://pastebin.com/N4ACz88H
Then, there is the BUILD.bazel file that is mentioned in the error, with path `/private/var/tmp/_bazel_lee/e8d7ac4c02a67f34deebe5eff64aac05/external/com_github_aws_aws_sdk_go_v2_service_sts/BUILD.bazel`. It looks like this: https://pastebin.com/DLEz0BZe

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide some context? do you generate the BUILD files with gazelle? it does seems like cross-module imports issue.